# The multi-part identifier could not be bound error won't fix

Tags: asp-classic

The Variable `fileName` contains the name of two columns to fetch value of it, which is in the type of `"email,address"`
The output of the `fileName` variable is `sam@gmail.com102streetN`, which is what I need

but when I try to insert that value into another column table then it throws me an error

```
The multi-part identifier "sam@gmail.com102streetN" could not be bound.
```

I don't know how to fix it

```
for each a in idParase

strSQL = "Select Award, Year, ("&fileName&") as dynamicColumns FROM dbo.Awards_TABLE Where awardID = "&a&""

cmdCRProc.CommandText = strSQL  
Set rsCR = cmdCRProc.Execute 

nameParase = rsCR("dynamicColumns")


sql2 = "Insert Into dbo.Queue (Award,Year,awardID,FileName) Values ("&rsCR(0)&", "&rsCR(1)&", "&a&", "&nameParase&") " 


cmdCRProc.CommandText = sql2  
Set rsCR = cmdCRProc.Execute 

next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't going wrong in the INSERT, but in the SELECT.
If I write out your SELECT it would be something this I think (I don't know the value of "a", but let's say it's 2):

```
Select Award, Year, (sam@gmail.com102streetN) as dynamicColumns FROM dbo.Awards_TABLE Where awardID = 2
```

I very much doubt you have a column named `'sam@gmail.com102streetN'`, right?
I don't know what your goal is, but it seems like you're building a query with a dynamic column name that doesn't exist.

What you can do is `Response.Write()` your SQL statements and see what the result is. Then maybe run them in your database management tool to check what's going on:

`Response.write(strSQL)`

And

`Response.write(sql2)`